# C++ multi threading with zeroMQ

Tags: c++, multithreading, zeromq

I'm implementing a GUI application that makes use of a notification system based on zeroMQ (OpenBTS physical status API).
I understand i have to put the zeroMQ receiver in a separate thread to not block the interface, but i do not know what type of threading methods to implement.
Thanks in advance!

edit: the zeroMQ code for the receiver, is

```
zmq::context_t context(4);
zmq::socket_t targetPublisher(context, ZMQ_SUB);
std::string localopenbts = "tcp://127.0.0.1:45160";

targetPublisher.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);
targetPublisher.connect(localopenbts.c_str());
while (1) {
    try {
        zmq::message_t event;
        targetPublisher.recv(&event);
        std::cout << std::string(static_cast<char*>(event.data()), event.size()) << std::endl;

    } catch(const zmq::error_t& e) {
        std::cout << "!! exception !!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

To not block the GUI, i understood that i need to run the endless loop in a separate thread. I do not know however how to implement that correctly.

Thank you again.

Comment: Please share some code, otherwise we can't help you, thanks

Comment: As unspecific as the question is, I think this is more a design/architecture question and not a specific multi-threading question. The communication thread will have to communicate with the UI thread when a message is received. How do you plan to do this? UI frameworks are usually not thread-safe, so you need some form of context switch, e.g. via the event loop or with the Command pattern. An alternative would be a different design, e.g. Reactor-based integrating message and UI.

Comment: sorry for th question style, still new here. I previously done something similar in c# leveraging the await-async construct. To be more specific is there anything similar in c++?

Comment: @FC C++ has Futures with std::async, but you will still have to propagate the message back in the UI thread. I think C#'s async/await does that for you if you use WPF. C++ does not have such a mechanism yet.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, something like this:

```
void receiveFunction(const std::string& uri)
{
    // the code from your question goes here, using OpenMQ
}

int main()
{
    std::thread receiveThread(receiveFunction, "tcp://127.0.0.1:45160");

    // do GUI stuff here
}
```

This will start a new thread (`receiveThread`) early on, which can be used entirely to run the ZeroMQ code you posted.  You're then free to do anything else in the original thread.

If you need to pass data from the receive thread to the GUI thread, you might want to look at what facilities your GUI library provides (you didn't tell us which GUI library you're using, however).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm using wxWidget for the GUI. As far as i understand, using threads from the GUI framework should be safer, right?

Comment: @FC: I don't see why thread wrappers in wxWidgets would be safer than std::thread, but they probably aren't any worse either.  Use whichever you prefer.  Ultimately I expect they're all `pthread`s.